# Perform Varying Until sub equals 0

Tags: cobol

Just a quick question here, how would COBOL deal with the following statement?

```
MOVE ZERO TO WS-SUB-2.
```

And then later:

```
PERFORM A100
        VARYING WS-SUB FROM 1 BY 1
        UNTIL WS-SUB > WS-SUB-2.
```

Reason being is I have a perform varying until where 2 variables are compared, but "WS-SUB-2" can be zero. I just need to know if "A100" would ever be performed.

Comment: No. If those are consecutive code lines, for instance, A100 will never be PERFORMed from there. You *can* use WITH TEST AFTER, which would ensure you do the A100 once. Better to structure your code to "explain" the data than fiddle around to reduce lines of code.

Comment: And if those aren't consecutive lines of code, but WS-SUB-2 is zero when the PERFORM is encountered, it won't process as written, because the test is done first (BEFORE), by default, not AFTER.

Comment: I did try to type them as individual lines rather than all one line, not sure why it put them back on to one line, but thanks.

Comment: Most coders would avoid `WITH TEST AFTER`, I suspect, and would instead write `UNTIL WS-SUB > (WS-SUB-2 + 1)`.

Comment: @DavidGorsline I'd hope they'd code out what the implications of the zero are, separately, rather than trying to fudge it through the PERFORM just for the heck of it. Can't say what that may be without something more specific. I think you're right about "WITH TEST AFTER"-avoidance.

Answer (score 0):

`A100` is never executed.

`PERFORM` is a loop with an *explicit loop counter*, which means it knows about the sequencing of each iteration. What exactly happens, is this:

- `WS-SUB` is set to 1
- The expression `WS-SUB > WS-SUB-2` is evaluated.

  - If `WS-SUB is greater than WS-SUB-2`, then break out of the loop en continue with the next statement.
  - Else, then perform the `A100` procedure; and at last `WS-SUB` is incremented by 1.

Because at the very start `WS-SUB` is greater than `WS-SUB-2`, the perform statement is instantly terminated, thus `A100` is never executed.

It is a little hard to understand what exactly it is that you want. Here a few suggestions:

- If you want `A100` to be executed at least once, you can use this:

  ```
  IF WS-SUB-2 = ZERO
      MOVE 1 TO WS-SUB-2
  END-IF
  ```
- If you want to execute `A100` `WS-SUB-2 + 1` times, then either change `UNTIL WS-SUB > WS-SUB-2` TO `UNTIL WS-SUB > WS-SUB-2 + 1` or change `FROM 1` to `FROM 0`.

Comment: `IF WS-SUB-2 EQUAL TO ZERO PERFORM A100 ELSE dotheloop`

Answer (score 0):

No, A100 won't be executed.  Because `PERFORM` by default is `WITH TEST BEFORE`.  So as soon as  PERFORM detects WS-SUB (1) is greater than WS-SUB2 (0), it stops.  If you want A100 to perform once, you can use `PERFORM WITH TEST AFTER`.  And in this case, A100 will run once.